# Missing content in Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, jobs

[Stack Overflow Jobs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/jobs) page in the Help Center does not have any content.

> [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's close \[jobs\] questions!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377689/lets-close-jobs-questions) - There are no more Jobs / Careers at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops. Two issues there:

1. That category's content is still being prepared, so it's supposed to be hidden... except that I missed the sidebar on individual help articles.
2. Even with that in mind, it should only show up on Stack Overflow for obvious reasons.

I pushed a fix that'll be going live in a few minutes here, so the "Stack Overflow Jobs" link in the Help Center will not show up anymore.

Thanks for the report!