# Let's close [jobs] questions!

Tags: discussion, tags, jobs, vote-to-close

Stack Overflow [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Since most of the posts with [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) tag are not relevant today because of the discontinuation, let's close the posts. Feel free to share your opinion about closing these posts.

Also, I request the moderators or staff to remove the [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) and if needed, replace them with appropriate status tag.

---

I agree with [Bhargav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/311398/bhargav-rao)'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1260472). I do not think closing 2.18k posts is appropriate. Perhaps, we can close [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjobs%5D%20%5Bstatus-deferred%5D%20closed%3A0) posts.

Comment: Feels like a total waste of time and resources. Closing 2.5k questions would not just put an absurd amount of load on the close vote queue but also hinder the queue from closing those questions that actually require more immediate attention. If those old posts are bumped, then closing it would make sense, but going through a list of old questions and voting to closing them is just burning daylight.

Comment: There were a lot of questions tagged [tag:jobs] [tag:status-planned] which I previously requested for a moderator to clean up through a flag.

Comment: @BhargavRao I agree. How about closing these questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs+status-deferred ? Also, I am not sure why you said "2.5k", I can only see 2.18k questions.

Comment: You're still closing questions despite this having a net negative score. Perhaps you should hold off till it actually gains net support.

Comment: @RobertLongson OP isn't a mod, he can't close questions on his own. And if a mod doing it, well, that's their call, score is not relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar he can fill up the close queue though.

Comment: @RobertLongson well user with 3k rep has the right to vote to close any question they see fit, I don't see any harm in it. Close votes are rate limited (20 or 30 per day) and expire.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar if that's how you feel, feel free to upvote this question. It seems that not everyone else agrees though.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not talking about this specific case of rallying support for closing mass of questions, just saying I have no issue with OP casting single close votes where they see fit. I thought you meant [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377689/lets-close-jobs-questions?noredirect=1#comment1260559_377689) that many jobs questions are somehow getting actually closed, so guess it all began with misunderstanding. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Take a look at this https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/846219/random-person?tab=activity&sort=comments and search for "I'm voting to close".

Comment: My question for OP is: What is the benefit of closing them, what would that accomplish?

Comment: @RandomPerson no need, I can access to the close votes queue itself.

Answer (score 15):

No, let's not go actively find and close and/or edit these posts.

There is no harm done when leaving them open. They will get closed organically, if at all.

Also bumping posts to remove tags is a concern as it floods the front page and the active tab. Moderators and Community Managers have better things to do.

Just for reference: The sunsetting of [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocumentation%5D+closed%3A1) only had most of its questions closed a year later. We have time.

If anything, the tag wiki could be updated with moderation guidance, once we settled on one.

Answer (score 5):

Jobs/Careers was a mature product which had a fair amount of impact, positive or negative on the way the network has turned out. I wouldn't treat this the same as Documentation, which was a Beta and an attempt to extend the Q&A format in other ways.

Even as a defunct product, there may be value in keeping documentation of it around for the future - as a matter of being a record of the history of the network and its various components.

While it's tempting to focus on moving things to the outpile of meta, I'd argue that the effort spent might be better spent elsewhere.

Someone misattributed once "Thou Shalt not Kill, yet not need to strive officiously to keep alive". If one comes across such a post organically - voting to close or getting it retagged is fine. It's probably not a good use of time (and risks flooding the front page) to concertedly close or 'fix' these.

Comment: Well, I am not talking about deleting the posts. I am just talking about closing them. Will closing posts lead to deletion?

Comment: Does closing posts bring them to front page? I don't think so.